# lsp-mode's magic to prevent C-x 1 from working?

Tags: frames, lsp-mode, emacs28

When I start emacs all functionality of frames works fine.
I can split frame by two via "C-x 3", switch to it "C-x o",
and then close other (left) frame via "C-x 1".

But after I activate error frame on the bottom via pressing
with mouse on error counter on the status bar (on screenshot bellow),
and then close error frame, then "C-x 1" stops working.
I still can use "C-x 3" and "C-x o",
but "C-x 1" inside the right frame do not work anymore,
it works only inside the left frame.

How lsp-mode do this, and how can I fix it?

[image: lsp-mode magic error buffer]

Comment: To clarify, your Emacs looks like the image. You're focus is in the "main.cpp" window, and you're trying to close the "Errors List" window via `C-x 1`. Correct?

Comment: Oh, that _is_ irritating. Doing `C-x o` followed by `q` works, as does `mouse-3` on the "Errors List" modeline. Smells like a bug to me, but then I'm not a heavy `lsp-mode` user. When I do use it, I use `flycheck`'s error list (`C-c ! l`).

Comment: @nega No, all begins after I close "Errors List". After It shows and closed, "C-x 1" stops working in all other frames, except left one. So showing of this "Errors List" change some global state/variable. But which one I have no idea, and that's why is my question.

Comment: Oh, I can't reproduce that.

Comment: I can reproduce that (Emacs29) if I open first an ```.org``` file and then a ```.cpp``` file. But, the Emacs user manual say this: >C-x 1 (delete-other-windows) deletes all the windows, except the selected one; the selected window expands to use the whole frame. (This command cannot be used while the minibuffer window is active; attempting to do so signals an error.)